# jQuery if in array but exclude some string

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

I have six option values from database table similar to this: #blog and #hariciURL and #portfolio blah blah blah similar like this.

I have another table have that values, I check if same values in the array that option value will be disabled but except #hariciURL option value never disable.

How can I exclude #hariciURL not disabled from this option menu?
please check codes you can understand what I mean.

sorry, my bad English.

```js
    $().ready(function() {

        $('#degeriAL option').each(function() { // option menüsündeki tüm değerleri al
            //console.log(BolumleriAl);
            var BolumleriAl = $(this).val(); // tüm valuelerini bir değişkene ata
            

            var seolink = ("#services", "#hariciURL"); 
            
//var seolink = "<?php echo $BolumVarmiSorgula->seolink;?>"; // this original code come from database.
             console.log(seolink);
            var bolumisimleri = $('#degeriAL option[name]');
            
            var exclude = "#hariciURL"; //this will be never disabled


            if ($.inArray(seolink, BolumleriAl) && BolumleriAl !== exclude) { // iki dizi içinde eşleşen varmı diye bak

                $('#degeriAL option[value="' + seolink + '"]').prop("disabled", true).addClass("secimMenusuDisabled").addClass(".secimMenusuDisabled" + "(bölüm mevcut)").nextAll(); //option menüdeki dizi içinde olan tüm  değerlerini veritabanından gelenlerle karşılaştır ve eşleşenleri option menü içinden disabled yap
            }

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="degeriAL" name="bolumLink" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
      <option value="" required="">Bölüm Seçiniz...</option>
      <option value="#featured-services"> Diğer Hizmetler </option>
      <option value="#about"> Hakkımızda </option>
      <option value="#services"> Hizmetler </option>
      <option value="#call-to-action"> Tıklama Eylemi </option>
      <option value="#blog"> Blog </option>
      <option value="#skills"> Yatay İstatistik Çizelgesi </option>
      <option value="#facts"> Rakamsal İstatistik </option>
      <option value="#portfolio"> Ürünler </option>
      <option value="#clients"> Referansların Logoları </option>
      <option value="#testimonials"> Müşteri Görüşleri </option>
      <option value="#team"> Bizim Takım &amp; Çalışanlar </option>
      <option value="#contact"> İletişim / Form / Harita </option>
      <option value="#hariciURL"> Harici Link </option>
    </select>
```

```
$('#degeriAL option').each(function() {
  var BolumleriAl = $(this).val();

  var seolink = "<?php echo $BolumVarmiSorgula->seolink;?>";
  var bolumisimleri = $('#degeriAL option[name]');

  var Exclude = "#hariciURL"; //this will be never disabled


  if (jQuery.inArray(seolink, BolumleriAl)) {

    $('#degeriAL option[value="' + seolink + '"]').prop("disabled", true).addClass("secimMenusuDisabled").addClass(".secimMenusuDisabled" + "(that already exist, you can not add more than one)").nextAll();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you just include an additional condition to your if statement such as if (jQuery.inArray(seolink, BolumleriAl && $(this).id !== Exclude)) I'm assuming 'Exclude' refers to the ID of the option here though.

Comment: Or just remove the item that will never be disabled from your array of things to disable? If you could make this just client side (Put in some example data for your PHP echo if you can) and show us the `select` element it would help clarify the question.

Comment: Code is wrong. `$.inArray` expects a string and an array, and your code passes two strings. That means it will always return -1 which is truthy so everything will be disabled. Show what `seolink` contains and show the rendered html of the `#degeriAL`

Comment: this is seolink values: #hariciURL

#services

Comment: @DoganOzer post the rendered script not the one with `php`. We need to see what the script looks like in your browser.

Comment: i edited my main top of message, i added there.

Comment: @DoganOzer good. Can you please do the same for the script ?

Comment: As mentioned by Gabriele Petrioli, `inArray()` does not return a boolean.  It returns [-1, 0, ..., n-1] where -1 is not found.  Your conditional will have to check that the value is not -1 to know it was found.

Comment: i edited my top messages, but just last value disabled, normaly  variables come from database and it working normaly. but here why just last item disabling i am not understand.

Comment: @DoganOzer `("#services", "#hariciURL")` is not an array. Arrays are denoted with `[]` not `()`. Also `var seolink = "<?php echo $BolumVarmiSorgula->seolink;?>"` can never render as `var seolink = ("#services", "#hariciURL")` since there are `"` around it in the php version that do not show in the rendered version.

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli thanks for the notice, i see now. bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want is

1. since the `seolinks` seems to be a string, you need to `split` it so that it becomes an array.
2. check that the `BolumleriAl` is not the same as the `Exclude`

   - if they are different then check if it is found in the `seolinks` array and if so then disable it
3. you are already iterating over the `option` elements so no need to use a selector to find the element to disable. Just use `this`.

```js
$('#degeriAL option').each(function() {
  var BolumleriAl = $(this).val();

  var seolink = "<?php echo $BolumVarmiSorgula->seolink;?>".split(' ');

  var Exclude = "#hariciURL"; //this will be never disabled

  if (BolumleriAl !== Exclude && $.inArray(BolumleriAl, seolink) > -1) {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true)
      .addClass("secimMenusuDisabled")
      //.addClass(".secimMenusuDisabled" + "(that already exist, you can not add more than one)");
  }
});
```

Comment: I think my mistake am i not create array, am I wrong?

Comment: @DoganOzer one of the problems was that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the options, so you can just check if the option value, `BolumleriAl`, is not the excluded one.

Also, You can move the variables seolink and Exclude out of the loop, as these do change not every time.

```js
var seolink = "https://example.com";
var Exclude = "#hariciURL"; //this will be never disabled
var Bölümler = ['test3', 'test7'];

$('#degereriAL').children('option').each(function() {
  var currentValue = $(this).val();

  if (currentValue == Exclude || $.inArray(currentValue, Bölümler) > -1) {
    // The value is excluded (#hariciURL)
    // OR the value is in the Bölümler array
  } else {
    $(this)
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .addClass("secimMenusuDisabled");
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 10em;
}

select option[disabled] {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="degereriAL" size="8">
  <option value="https://example.com">Test</option>
  <option value="#hariciURL">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
  <option value="test6">Test 6</option>
  <option value="test7">Test 7</option>
  <option value="test8">Test 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: still #hariciURL is disabling, not work codes sorry.

Comment: @DoganOzer: I've added a working example. Maybe you can use that to find out why it isn't working?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply and helps, but i fixed it long time ago, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understoud from your question, I think your if condition was inverted.

Also, you should use the value given by $.each function

```
var seolink = "<?php echo $BolumVarmiSorgula->seolink;?>";
var Exclude = "#hariciURL"; //this will be never disabled

$('#degeriAL option').each(function(i,v) {

  Exclude = v != Exclude && $.inArray(seolink, v) ?  $('#degeriAL option[value="' + seolink + '"]').prop("disabled", true).addClass("secimMenusuDisabled").text('that already exist, you can not add more than one') : "#hariciURL";

});
```